# Convert date to unix timestamp in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, unix-timestamp

I have a table with a column abc carrying the unix timestamp (eg. 13898161481435) and I want to run a between dates select.

It would be not efficient to do a

```
where TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(abc / 1000), 'DD/MM/YYYY') > '14/01/2014 00:00:00' and ..;
```

which would convert every record.

Rather do something like
*where abc > ('14/01/2014 00:00:00' tobigint()) and abc < ...*

But I cant find any reference, though for the reverse case.

Answer (score 37):

Try this

```
WHERE abc > extract(epoch from timestamp '2014-01-28 00:00:00')
```

## [PostgreSQL Docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: You could use this also for the exact date with a simple modification like `select extract(epoch from now())`

Answer (score 5):

You do not need to convert it to char to compare it.

```
WHERE to_timestamp(abc/1000) > timestamp '2014-01-28 00:00:00'
```

I don't think that conversion would be very inefficient because timestamps are stored internally in a similar format to epoch secs (admittedly with a different origin and resolution).

If you really want to go the other way:

```
WHERE abc > extract(epoch from timestamp '2014-01-28 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting observation though, while

```
select count(*) from cb.logs where to_timestamp(timestmp/1000) > timestamp '2014-01-15 00:00:00' and to_timestamp(timestmp/1000) < timestamp '2014-01-15 23:59:59';
```

takes almost 10 seconds (my db with 1,5 mill records), the below only 1,5 sec

```
select count(*) from cb.logs where (timestmp > (select extract(epoch from timestamp '2014-01-15 00:00:00') * 1000) and timestmp < (select extract(epoch from timestamp '2014-01-15 23:59:59') * 1000));
```

and the below about 1sec

```
select count(*) from cb.logs where (timestmp > extract(epoch from timestamp '2014-01-15 00:00:00') * 1000) and (timestmp < extract(epoch from timestamp '2014-01-15 23:59:59') * 1000);
```

to count ~40.000 records

Most likely because the division I would say.

Comment: The first query cannot use an index defined on the column `timestmp` whereas the other two can. Check the execution plan.

Comment: I'm with horse. There is no way any arithmetic operation could make that difference. Would be interesting to see 'explain analyse' for those cases.

Answer (score 2):

1

```
select count(*) from cb.logs where to_timestamp(timestmp/1000) > timestamp '2014-01-15 00:00:00' and to_timestamp(timestmp/1000) < timestamp '2014-01-15 23:59:59';  
8600ms

"Aggregate  (cost=225390.52..225390.53 rows=1 width=0)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on logs  (cost=0.00..225370.34 rows=8073 width=0)"
"        Filter: ((to_timestamp(((timestmp / 1000))::double precision) > '2014-01-15 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (to_timestamp(((timestmp / 1000))::double precision) < '2014-01-15 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))"
```

2

```
select count(*) from cb.logs where (timestmp > (select extract(epoch from timestamp '2014-01-15 00:00:00') * 1000) and timestmp < (select extract(epoch from timestamp '2014-01-15 23:59:59') * 1000));
1199ms
"Aggregate  (cost=209245.94..209245.95 rows=1 width=0)"
"  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)"
"    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)"
"  InitPlan 2 (returns $1)"
"    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on logs  (cost=0.00..209225.74 rows=8073 width=0)"
"        Filter: (((timestmp)::double precision > $0) AND ((timestmp)::double precision < $1))"
```